# Converting WriteableBitmap to Bitmap in C#

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap, writeablebitmap

Is there any way for converting [WriteableBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.aspx) to [Bitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx) in C# ?

Comment: @GeorgeJohnston BitmapImage is in the System.Windows.Media namespace. Bitmap is in the System.Drawing namespace. The methods to convert between the two are entirely different.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward, actually.  Here's some code that *should* work.  I haven't tested it and I'm writing it from the top of my head.

```
private System.Drawing.Bitmap BitmapFromWriteableBitmap(WriteableBitmap writeBmp)
{
  System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp;
  using (MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream())
  {
    BitmapEncoder enc = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
    enc.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create((BitmapSource)writeBmp));
    enc.Save(outStream);
    bmp = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(outStream);
  }
  return bmp;
}
```

The WriteableBitmap inherits from a BitmapSource, which can be saved directly to a stream.  Then, you build a Bitmap from this stream.

Comment: As an aside, you'll need PresentationCore and WindowsBase for .Net 3.5. For .Net 4, you'll also need System.Xaml. Don't know why that is. I'm using these references in an Asp.NET application to generate QR codes for TOTP authentication.

Comment: For some operations, `Bitmap` requires the underlying stream to be open when the bitmap was created from a stream. For example, `bmp.Save(filename)` will not work.